# Question tag change after answering it

Tags: discussion, support, tags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076887/ternary-assignment-how-to-read) is originally tagged with `java`. So I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34076909/2317535) the question based on `java`. But later OP edit tag and tag it with `c`. What is your suggestion about  handle this situation?

Comment: Downvote and move on.

Comment: I was tempted to give the OP the benefit of the doubt, but unless they have a macro to redefine `NULL` to `null`, I'm not so sure.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions ?

Comment: Edits that invalidate existing answers to a question should be rolled back or otherwise undone. However, it's difficult to actually accomplish that as a 3rd party editor; most people in the edit review queue reject these edits if you say that you're fixing changes that invalidate the answers. You may be better off leaving a comment telling the OP not to make changes that make existing answers wrong (and of course, down voting the question).

Comment: What if the asker never tags it with a language, then downvotes *every* answer submitted without editing or leaving a comment? [cough, this question, cough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071163/want-to-get-string-character-by-character/).  Not that I care about 2 rep points, but I did genuinely want to help the guy.

Comment: @Draco18s that question seems like a good candidate for "Unclear what you're asking"

Comment: Mm, that's true.

Comment: @Draco18s Are you sure that the OP has downvoted? He has not cast even a single vote, AFAIK.

Comment: No, I don't know it was the OP.  All votes are anonymous of course, but even after I commented about it, there has been no activity.  All three answers were downvoted at roughly the same time (I was browsing SO when it happened and when I loaded the page a moment after getting the notification, all three were downvoted).  I held off for a while before commenting, just in case an edit or comment was still being written.  Anyway, it was just something that made me raise an eyebrow.